# window.opener lost after split screen in iOS safari

Tags: javascript, safari, postmessage, ipados, window.opener

I have a website where a popup window is opened by:

```js
// main window
const url = ...
const popup = window.open(url, "popup_workflow", "popup=yes")
```

And I rely on `popup_workflow` window's opener to communicate workflow result.

```js
// popup_workflow window
const result = ...
window.opener.postMessage(result , "*")
```

This workflow works in most browser, only breaks on an iPad when:

1. Open the `popup_workflow` window in safari.
2. Drag the tab of `popup_workflow` window to edge of iPad screen, open it in split view.
3. Now in the new `popup_workflow` window, `window.opener` is gone.

```js
// in main window, this does not work
popup.postMessage("something", "*")

// in popup_workflow window, this does not work
window.opener.postMessage("something", "*")
```

While I test in other OS or browser, `window.opener` will not lost even after refresh.

How could I get my opener back in iOS safari's split screen view?